# MySQL sotring by two culmns performance

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have that query:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `EpisodeDetailed`
    WHERE  Language LIKE "%en%"
      AND  AddedDate >= "2020-01-13"
      AND  (Tags="1509"
              OR  Tags LIKE "%1509"
              OR  Tags LIKE "1509%"
              OR  Tags LIKE "%1509%"
           )
    ORDER BY  AddedDate, Votes
    LIMIT  50
```

And it is less than 0,1s when I use:

```
ORDER BY AddedDate ASC, Votes ASC
```

or

```
ORDER BY AddedDate DESC, Votes DESC
```

but is very slow (about 4s) when I use

```
ORDER BY AddedDate ASC, Votes DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY AddedDate DESC, Votes ASC
```

Why?

My indexes:
[image]

Comment: Curious ORDER BY AddedDate, Votes is the same as ORDER BY AddedDate ASC, Votes ASC , ASC being the default.

Comment: you have indexes  on column AddedDate and Votes??

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN SELECT...` output?

Answer (score 1):

You have an index on `AddedDate asc, Votes asc`.

MySQL can (apparently) use this in two ways:

1. It can start at the beginning and scan to the end.  That supports `order by AddedDate asc, Votes asc`.
2. It can start at the end and scan to the beginning.  That supports `order by AddedDate desc, Votes desc`.

What it is not doing is jumping to each value of `AddedDate` and scanning *backwards* for that value.  Alas.  It decides it needs to sort the data separately.

You could add an index on `AddedDate asc, Votes desc` for the other two cases.

Comment: How to add it? I tried "CREATE INDEX test_stack ON EpisodeDetailed (AddedDate asc, Votes desc)" but it appears that it created normal index ignoring asc and desc

Comment: @MateuszKaflowski. . . You can review the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html.  MySQL does support them but it depends on the version of MySQL and the storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to alter your query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `EpisodeDetailed` 
WHERE `Language` RLIKE 'en' 
AND `AddedDate` >= "2020-01-13" 
AND `Tags` RLIKE '1509' 
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`AddedDate`) ASC, `Votes` DESC LIMIT 50;
```

In addition, just in case you have `MariaDB` installed, have a look [here](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/descending-indexes-in-mariadb/#:%7E:text=Since%20the%20dawn%20of%20time,is%20perfectly%20legal%20in%20MySQL.) also. I think you will find it most interesting.

Comment: RLIKE tends to be slower than LIKE.  Function calls in `ORDER BY` eliminates any index usage.  Mixed directions (ASC/DESC)  cannot use an index (until MySQL 8.0).

Comment: @RickJames You are correct, `RLIKE` tends to be a bit slower but if the table is correctly indexed there is a minor difference. And yes MIxed directions is only a feature of `MySQL` 8.

Comment: `RLIKE`, as far as I know, never uses an index.  `LIKE 'abc%'` can use an index; it is effectively a "range".  However, a leading wildcard is used for both `language` and `Tags`, thereby preventing any useful index.

Comment: @RickJames there was a request wayyy back at 2003 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=747 to speed up regular expressions more by the beneficial use of indexes nut no luck... But you are correct `RLIKE` does not benefit from indexes, but we talk about regular expressions so the intention is to be fast after all even when scanning more rows. If the dataset is too large then a better approach should be made either on the query or the table design.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things preventing a speedup of that query:

- LIKE with leading wildcard cannot use an index
- Multiple ranges in the WHERE clause (you have 3) cannot be optimize.  One may be an index, but the others cannot.
- Without an ORDER BY, the execution simply plods through the table, checking each row.  If there is also a LIMIT, the query may *or may not* finish rapidly, depending on how many rows match and where they occur in the table.
- With an ORDER BY (and because no index can handle all the WHERE), the execution must all the matching rows before thinking about the ORDER BY or LIMIT.
- Sometimes using an index is slower than not.  This happens when most of the rows need to be checked but the Optimizer fails to recognize it.  It can be slower because an index needs to reach over into the data to see the rest of the row.

Maybe...

- Look at `language`.  Perhaps `en` is always on the left?  If so, `LIKE 'en%'` might be slightly faster.
- What about `FULLTEXT` for `tags`?  If it is applicable, it will be a *lot* faster to use `MATCH(tags) AGAINST('+1509' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND the other clauses`.

Comment: MATCH AGAINST helps a lot. Thanks.